# Access only one attribute of API in response - Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am calling an API that returns an array of JSON objects and I can access return values of the API call

```
[{"param1":1,"param2":"blah1"},
{"param1":2,"param2":"blah2"},
{"param1":3,"param2":"blah3"}]
```

I know that i can access each Param1 through iteration or by static indexing like `@client[0].param1`  `@client[1].param1`  `@client[2].param1` but the thing is , i don't want param2 and i want just param1 . is there any way , to access param1 without iteration or static indexing 
so that i could get the below result in response

```
[{"param1":1},
{"param1":2},
{"param1":3}]
```

**Update**

> The thing to notice is that i want to filter the result while making
>   the request (before getting the response when we know the attribute
>   name)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `delete`.

> Deletes and returns a key-value pair from hsh whose key is equal to
>   key. If the key is not found, returns the default value. If the
>   optional code block is given and the key is not found, pass in the key
>   and return the result of block.

```
data = [{"param1":1,"param2":"blah1"},
{"param1":2,"param2":"blah2"},
{"param1":3,"param2":"blah3"}]

data.each {|x| x.delete("param2")}
```

For more information about [delete](http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/delete).
I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response dear, but i think i could not make myself clear . kindly have a look on the question again and answer again if possible . thanks in advance , By the way , the thing you did is right , we can also take advantage of ruby 'map' method and some other also , but only when we'll have response . I want to filter the data before getting response